# htaccess rewrite works only on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the subdomain "m" from all the pages but how-ever i try it works only on the main domain..

I tried this-

```
#for all requests to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.m\.pcgraph\.co\.il$

#redirect them to new-example
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pcgraph.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.pcgraph\.co\.il [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.pcgraph.co.il/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And few more variations but i keep getting the same results..

If i try to enter m.pcgraph.co.il it works fine but when i try to go to inner pages, the "m" subdomain remains.. E.g- m.pcgraph.co.il/something/ doesn't rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `$` to the end of your `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That should definitely work. (I've tested it at my end).

If it doesn't, there may be a clash with other `mod_rewrite` directives (in the same or other `.htaccess` files).